# Typescript: How to get typechecking while mapping over a list

Tags: typescript, typescript2.9

Im using Typescript 2.9.1. Example of my problem:

```
type MyType = {
  replaceThisProp: string
}

const instance:MyType = {
  replaceThisProp: 'hello',
}

const instanceList:MyType[] = [instance]

// Misspelling the property here causes an error:
const updatedInstance:MyType = {
    ...instance,
    replaceThisPropp:'Oops'
}

// But here no error is given:
const result: MyType[] = instanceList.map<MyType>(h =>({
  ...h,
  replaceThisPropp:'Oops'
}))
```

I understand that Typescript can't determine the type as it is returned in the callback function. But what is the least verbose way of getting good type checking?

Comment: Which Typescript version are you using? For me Typescript (3.0.3) is able to infer the type of values passed to the callback.

Comment: Aha, Im using 2.9.1. I'll specify that in the question.

Comment: @Mathyn I still have the problem in typescript 3. To clarify my problem: I want to get an error in the map callback function since the property is misspelled. Did you get this error?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Madara has the right idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[].map` is designed to allow you to change the type, so it doesn't know your intent is to return `MyType`. You can tell it:

```
const result = instanceList.map((h): MyType =>({
  ...h,
  replaceThisPropp:'Oops' // now errors.
}))
```

Comment: This looks like a good answer. I guess Im confused as to why ".map<MyType>" was not enough. It seems as if functions simple are allowed to return subclasses of their return type unless specified when the function is instanced, as it is in your answer.

Comment: The reason why `.map<MyType>` is not enough is because `[].map` has the type `map<U>(callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];`. The generic `U` is the return type of the callback function which you want to be `{ replaceThisProp: string }` but you end up returning `{ replaceThisProp: string, replaceThisPropp: string }` which is still assignable to `{replaceThisProp: string }` as `replaceThisPropp` is just an extra property, so there is no error. There is no type error here, just a logic error.